# playframework disable CSRF filter

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, csrf

We have a play application written in Scala. We wanted to completely disable CSRF filter based on our requirement. there is no much instruction given on the play document (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCsrf) . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's enabled by default?

Comment: not sure. say for example. If I have a scrip that I want to access a rest URL it does not allow. That means it is enabled by default right?

Comment: @Prakash it is only enabled by default in 2.6, in 2.5 it isn't, so you like have some other problem with your request

Comment: @Qingwei I got it resolved. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using compile-time dependency injection, the runtime configuration for filters is ignored. Instead, you need to put code into your ApplicationLoader:

```
override def httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = {
  super.httpFilters.filterNot(_.getClass == classOf[CSRFFilter])
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#Compile-Time-Default-Filters

Comment: This only will help if you using construction as following 
`Server.withApplicationFromContext() { context => new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with HttpFiltersComponents {} }` in tests like me =) Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to disable the CSRF filter, as far as version 2.6 goes, is to add the following line to application.conf:

```
play.filters.disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```

See [Disabling Default Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#disabling-default-filters) in Play Framework documentation.

Comment: Regarding your specific case, @Prakash, you also need to upgrade to [Kohlberg's Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg%27s_stages_of_moral_development#Formal_elements) version 3 as soon as possible.