# Working in Get Method But not working in Post

Tags: playframework, soapui

I'm using Play Framework Scala and SoapUI. I have an authorization where I'll put a code in header. It's working in `GET`, but when put it in `POST`, it shows an error like this:

> a.ErrorHandler - onClientError: statusCode = 403, uri =
>   /v1/search/add/, message = No CSRF token found in headers

Comment: Update the question to the code inserted one.

Comment: Thats really not much to go on. Could you possibly submit screenshots of both your GET and POST teststeps? Maybe also copy/paste the RAW request from both, so we can see what is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the csrf token with POST requests.  You can disable the csrf token, that is the easyest way, and it is answered here: 
[playframework disable CSRF filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581985/playframework-disable-csrf-filter)

But I recoment not to disable csrf token in live application for security reasons.

Comment: How do I add the CSRF filter for me to add the CSRF token